# File menus are not selectable for unity3d on kubuntu

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, kde-plasma

hey I am new to linux ( kubuntu 19.10 ). I installed kubuntu and did some UI tweaking, after that I installed unity3d 2019.3 game engine from unity hub. When I opened it, sub menus of file menu are not selectable. Other apps are working fine

[image: Unity3d edit menu]

I have no idea whats going on ... plz help.
I will be happy to provide any info you want

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround and that is to remove global menu...
Though I still dont know why there is a problem with unity3d and kde global menu